# Confusion about the derivation of stress tensor OPE from Ward Identity

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, ward-identity

I apologize for any difficulty in expressing my review. Allow me to briefly summarize the material and then pose my question.

**Review**

In [David Tong's string lecture note](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), he derives the OPE between stress tensor and the primary field $\mathcal{O}$ in the following way (in 2 dimension):

1. Consider the conformal transformation : $z \to z + \epsilon(z)$. We promote $\epsilon(z) \to \epsilon(z)f(\bar{z})$. Calculate the variation of the action w.r.t. the **metric**:

$$\delta S = \int d^2 \sigma \frac{\partial S}{\partial g^{\alpha\beta}}\delta g^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z T_{zz}\epsilon(z)\partial_{\bar{z}}f(\bar{z})$$

**Hence, the conserved charge of conformal symmetry is** $T\epsilon$.

2. **Ward Identity** : Let $\phi \to \phi + \epsilon \delta\phi$ be a global symmetry. Promoting $\epsilon \to \epsilon(x)$, we should have :

$$\delta S[\phi] \sim \int \epsilon \partial_{\alpha}J^{\alpha} $$

We further assume the measure $\mathcal{D}\phi$ in the path integral is invariant under such change. Then, we have :

$$\int\mathcal{\phi}e^{-S[\phi]}\mathcal{O}\cdots = \int\mathcal{\phi'}e^{-S[\phi']}\mathcal{O'}\cdots $$
Expanding R.H.S. to the first order, we can obtain :

$$\int \partial_{\alpha}\left\langle J^{\alpha}\mathcal{O}\cdots  \right\rangle = \left \langle \delta \mathcal{O}\cdots  \right\rangle$$

3. By considering the conformal symmetry :$J = T\epsilon$ and the definition of $\mathcal{O}$ being a primary field, we can obtain the OPE :

$$T(z)\mathcal{O}(w) = h \frac{\mathcal{O}(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{O}(w)}{z-w} + \text{r.e.g}$$

where $h$ is the conformal weight of $\mathcal{O}$.

**Question**

My question appears at the third step. **Why the author can consider** $J=T\epsilon$.

In the first step, the author derives the Noether conserved charge from variating the action w.r.t. the **metric**.

However, as deriving the Ward identity, I believe the author do the calculations in the flat space since including path integral of the metric has some problem about how to fix the gauge but the author doesn't mention it at this step.

It seems to me that the author assumes that obtaining the conserved charge from varying the action w.r.t. $g^{\alpha\beta}$ is equivalent to w.r.t. $\phi$, which is not the metric, in the flat space.

I think the assumption is somehow equivalent to assuming that the two definitions of stress-tensor

(1)$$T^{\alpha\beta} \sim \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha\beta}}$$

(2) Conserved charge generated from translation symmetry in the flat space : $\phi \to \phi + \epsilon^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi$

are equivalent.